# Observable with optional subscribers execute once

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

How can an `Observer` have its logic execute once (asynchronously) regardless of subscribers.  My use-case is a `Provider` class that does CRUD for a `Model` class by delegating to another object (`SqliteOpenHelper`). A call to `ModelProvider.update` should persist changes to the model, whether the UI subscribes or not.

```
class ModelProvider {
    Observable<String> updateModel(Model model) {
        return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) -> {
            // synchronous for now, probably irrelevant
            String modelId = repository.save(model);
            subscriber.onNext(modelId);
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}

class SomeActivity {
    void updateModel(Model model) {
        // dont care about the result, but need it to execute exactly once
        mModelProvider.updateModel(model);
    }
}
```

I'm in the middle of moving a codebase to using RxJava and reactive patterns so the call to `repository.save(model)` is synchronous, but will still need the logic to execute exactly once afterwards, with or without UI subscribers.

I've considered simply moving the repository logic out of the observable and then returning a different observable that uses the result of that:

```
class ModelProvider {
    Observable<String> updateModel(Model model) {
        String modelId = repository.save(model);

        return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) -> {
            subscriber.onNext(modelId);
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
}
```

but this forces the IO work on the main thread and blocks it.

another non-solution here:

```
    Observable<String> updateModel(Model model) {
        Observable<String> obs = Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) -> {
        String modelId = repository.save(model);
            subscriber.onNext(modelId);
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

        obs.subscribe();

        return obs;
    }
```

this does execute once at `obs.subscribe()` but executes again if the UI subscribes to it.

I'm just now learning reactive patterns but I assume this is where `Subjects`/`Relays` are useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works:

```
Observable<String> updateModel(Model model) {
    Observable<String> obs = Observable.create((Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) -> {
        String modelId = repository.save(model);
        subscriber.onNext(modelId);
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

    // cached() returns a new observer over the original, which only executes once
    // but not until it is subscribed to
    Observable<String> cachedObs = obs.cache();
    // this "starts" execution of `repository.save()`
    cachedObs.subscribe();

    // return observable that executes once and caches (cachedObs)
    // returning the original (obs) would cause multiple executions
    return cachedObs;
}
```

calling `Observable.cache()` after it's created prevents re-invocation, but the call to `obs.subscribe()` is needed in order to get that *one-and-only-one* invocation.

Note that the persistence block (`repository.save()` etc..) doesn't start immediately on subscription, but is queued to execute asynchronously on a separate thread (`Schedulers.io` thread-pool) at an indeterminate point in the future.

---

this uses `rxjava-async-utils` package and also works:

```
Observable<String> updateModel(Model model) {
    Observable<String> obs = Async.start(() -> repository.save(model));

    // cached() here is required in order to avoid the race condition
    Observable<String> cachedObs = obs.cache();

    return cachedObs;
}
```

Note that the call to `cache()` is required in order to save the result and provide it to subscribers.  Without it, there is a race condition where subscribers get no result because the `Async.start` block has already completed.

Answer (score 1):

As @xst said, but I'd simplify it more:

```
return Observable
     .defer(() -> Observable.just(repository.save(model)))
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .cache();
```

Comment: this does cache the response (and doesn't re-execute), but does not execute if there are no subscribers